# Разные шаблоны для вывода записей WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Как можно вывести цикл записей с двумя разными шаблонами? Мне нужно чтобы все четные были с одним шаблоном - нечетный с другим. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Считайте записи, берите остаток от целочисленного деления счетчика на два, сравнивайте его с нулем и делайте ветвление. А вообще-то тут принято свой код показывать.

Comment: Было бы неплохо показать коды шаблонов, возможно, есть другие пути

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде того :

```
$num = 1;
foreach($posts as $single_post) {
   if(($num % 2) == 0) {
      //если четное, выводим 1 шаблон
   } else {
      //если нечетное, выводим 2 шаблон
   }
   $num++;
}
```